# NSURLRequest setTimeoutInterval does not work as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, timeout, nsurlrequest

I have kept NSURLRequest timeout interval 30sec. And I have also configured the auto retry 3 times for request. So if any problem comes in request then total time should be 120 seconds (i.e. 2 mins).

But When i have kept Debug point on my server and if i request to server then my time out period is getting 3 minutes.

Can I configure this timeout??? Or it should work??

Is this default timeout interval Once request is made to Server??

Comment: Can you please explain the problem at hand more precisely.

Comment: @CodemasterGabriel: I am keeping breakpoint at server and then I am requesting to server. I have set my timeoutInterval to 30 sec. and i am retrying the request 3 times. So total is 120 secs. Now in first request only my connection is made to server but since my request is made so no retry will be there. In this case I have to wait for 3 mins for Connection timeout error instead of 2 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that 30 seconds times 3 is 90 seconds, or one and a half minutes, not 2 minutes.

As for the timeout problem, try to init your `NSURLRequest` with `initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`. Make sure to check the status of your `NSURLConnection` delegate methods, especially in `connection:didFailWithError:`.

Also, maybe you should explain how you measure the time out period on the server.

Comment: I have used same method and retrying 3 times apart from first time so total is 2 min and not 90 secs. I have checked the status code and i am getting **-1001** as status code which is for kCFURLErrorTimedOut.

Comment: So where is the problem? Your server is timing out and the callback is reporting this accurately.

Comment: But it takes 3 mins in all the cases.... So is it not configurable??? Or it is handled by OS itself??

Comment: You mean the `timeoutInterval` you set does not work? You set 30 secs and it only fails after 3 mins? That's really strange. Check again if `connection:didFailWithError:` is correctly informing you.

Comment: My timeoutInterval works Only if Request is not reached to server. But once my Request Hit to server than that TimeOut is not under User's control. Is this true??

Comment: No, the timeout will fire if you do not get a response from the server within the timeout.